# PhpUnit misconfiguration: no tests run when <directory> is used

Tags: php, phpunit

Using `PhpUnit 6.3` to test a `helloWorld()` function  written in `PHP 7.1`. The test runs ok if I execute its php file directly from the command line:

```
> php C:\path\to\phpunit.phar C:\project\hello-world\hello-world_tests.php
  OK <1 test, 1 assertion>
```

However if I rely on my configuration file, no test is run:

```
> php C:\path\to\phpunit.phar --configuration C:\project\phpunit.xml
  No tests executed!
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
project/
    phpunit.xml
    phpunit.phar
    hello-world/
        hello-world.php
        hello-world_test.php
```

Here is my configuration file, **phpunit.xml**:

```
<phpunit>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test suite">
            <directory>./hello-world</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Replacing the `directory` node with a `file` node gets things working:

```
<file>./hello-world/hello-world_test.php</file>
```

that's nice, but I don't want to list all test files individually, which is why I had the `directory` node originally.

Comment: AFAIR PHPUnit picks up only files named with trailing `Test` at the end --  making it to be `helloWorldTest.php` if to include file extenstion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<phpunit>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test suite">
            <directory suffix="_test.php">./hello-world</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```